# Invoke-ASCMD - passing values to XMLA file not working

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2014

I need to create a cmd file to backup Analysis Service Database. Because my SQL Server 2014 does not have ascmd.exe, I thought I would use PowerShell `Invoke-ASCMD` but I am having problems passing parameters to the XMLA file. Dbname and Backupfile parameters are not recognized in the XMLA file but when I hardcode values in their place, the script runs successfully.

Command file:

```batch
set DBNAME=ANALYSIS_DB
set SCRIPTPATH=E:\cube_backup.xmla
set SRC=ServerName\ServerInstance
set BACKUPPATH=G:\Cube_BackupFolder\

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:. " %%A in ('time/T') do (set var=%%A%%B%%C%)

set BACKUPFILE="%BACKUPPATH%\%DBNAME%_cube_%mydate%_%var%.abf"

powershell.exe -command Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile %SCRIPTPATH% -server %SRC%
```

SCRIPTPATH (XMLA code):

```xml
<Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>$dbname</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
    <File>$backupfile</File>
    <AllowOverwrite>false</AllowOverwrite>
</Backup>
```

Comment: Why don't you do this completely in PowerShell instead of calling PowerShell from a batch file?

Comment: Another point, if you are on 2014 why don't you just use the [`Backup-ASDatabase` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479574.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

`%DBNAME%` and `$dbname` are entirely different variables. They don't magically have the same value just because they have the same name. Also, PowerShell doesn't automagically expand variable names in XML files (see the answer to the [question you posted on the Technet forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f3195bc3-3816-4d97-84fc-6189892613ee/invokeascmd-passing-values-to-the-xmla-file?forum=winserverpowershell)).

You'd need to create the XML file on the fly with the values you want to use in order to make this work. Like this for instance:

```bsh
$dbname     = 'ANALYSIS_DB'
$xmlfile    = 'E:\cube_backup.xmla'
$server     = 'ServerName\ServerInstance'
$backupfile = "G:\Cube_BackupFolder\${dbname}_cube_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').abf"

$xml = @"
<Backup xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine'>
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>$dbname</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
    <File>$backupfile</File>
    <AllowOverwrite>false</AllowOverwrite>
</Backup>
"@

Invoke-ASCmd -InputFile $xmlfile -Server $server
```